# How to log exceptions thrown while Precondition check

Tags: java, guava

I'm intrested in using Guava libraries in my application.
Specially for Precondition and argument check.

But while Preconditions check it throws run time exception which is shown on console.
I want to log this exception.
Can any one tell me how to do that.

Thank in advance.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=guava+logging

Comment: you mean to ask how to write the text to a log file ? `PrintWriter out
   = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out"))); out.write(String message,..)`

Comment: @Bhaskar uhm, you are hopefully aware that there are many logging frameworks available in Java. You don't have to do that kind of low level logging yourself!

Comment: @Sean , Yes indeed. The point in my previous comment was just to highlight a simple and direct way to log a message, in case that was eluding the OP who, I am assuming, is new to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the pseudo-code

```
try
{
Precondition.(...);
}
catch(RuntimeException re)
{
//log the exception here
//rethrow re
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really cannot see, what good it would be to have the source of the RuntimeException do the logging ... When you use Preconditions, you guard your internal implementation by saying "you shall not pass, if your value is null (or if your length is more than x, or ...). You do this, because you dont want to deal with these constraints later in the code.

Whenever your method is called with illegal values, the caller gets an immediate RuntimeException, hopefully containing a helpful message ("setName(): name must not be null!"). 
Its now up to the caller to decide what to do with this information. Sometimes, you want to delegate the message to the user ("please enter a correct name"), sometimes you have to log an error, because you have a configuration problem (name should have been set by a system property).

My conclusion: just use checkArgument(), and let the caller (client) deal with the handling, logging etc. This in mind, you dont need any further code in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your preconditions as assertions (rather than input validation) I guess it makes sense to log violations of the precondition at the source (given that you then have a programming error in your code, and you cannot always trust your intermediate code to be well-behaved... :-)

If so you might be interested in having a look at valid4j with hamcrest-matchers (found on Maven Central as org.valid4j:valid4j)

For preconditions and postconditions (i.e. assertions throwing AssertionError()):

```
import static org.valid4j.Assertive.*;

require(argument, notNullValue());
require(x, greaterThan(0));
...
ensure(result, isValid());
```

Unfortunately the default implementation doesn't log the errors, but you can override an AssertiveProvider to log contract violations and register it as a ServiceLoader, i.e in META-INF/services.

See more at:

- http://www.valid4j.org/
- https://github.com/helsing/valid4j